# How to connect to a mongo DB via SSH using Python?

Tags: python, mongodb

Using python 3.10.10 on Windows 10 I am trying to connect to a `mongo` database via ssh ideally. On the command line I just do

```
ssh myuser@111.222.333.444
mongo
```

and I can query the mongo DB. With the following python code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure

HOST = "111.222.333.444"
USER = "myuser"

class Mongo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = HOST
        self.user = USER
        self.uri = f"mongodb://{self.user}@{self.host}"

    def connection(self):
        try:
            client = MongoClient(self.uri)
            client.server_info()
            print('Connection Established')
        except ConnectionFailure as err:
            raise(err)
        return client

mongo = Mongo()
mongo.connection()
```

however I get an error

```
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: A password is required.
```

But as I am able to just login via ssh using my public key I do not require a password. How can this be solved in python?

I also tried to run a command on the command line using `ssh` alone like

```
ssh myuser@111.222.333.444 "mongo;use mydb; show collections"
```

but this does not work like that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I found in the end, as simple as possible, and it can be run from within python, and without any special module to install, from a windows powershell:

```
import json
import subprocess

cmd_mongo = json.dumps('db.units.find({"UnitId": "971201065"})')
cmd_host = json.dumps(f"mongo mydb --eval {cmd_mongo}")
cmd_local = f"ssh {USER}@{HOST} \"{cmd_host}\""

output = subprocess.check_output(cmd_local, shell=True)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do two different things. In the first command you connect via ssh (using port 22) to the remote server. On the remote server you start the `mongo` shell. In the second command, you try to connect directly to the mongod server (default port 27017).

In your case `myuser` is the user on remote server operating system, not the user on the MongoDB.

You can (almost) always connect to a MongoDB without username/password, however when you provide a username then you also need a password. Try

```
self.uri = f"mongodb://{self.host}"
```

It is not fully clear what you try to achieve. You can configure MongoDB to logon with x509 certificate instead of username/password, see [Use x.509 Certificates to Authenticate Clients](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/). These connections are also encrypted via TLS/SSL.

Or are you looking to configure a SSH-Tunnel? See https://serverfault.com/questions/597765/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-server-via-ssh-tunnel

Comment: I want to create a python script to make a query on the remote mongo DB, so that I can do something like `result = make_query('db.units.find({"UnitId": "70040160011"})')'. I just tried the ssh tunnel idea but the command seems to hang ...